# webapicontroller only or both controller and webapi controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller

I am designing architecture for one small application, one of the requirements is to have everything exposed as services.  I know that with web api controllers thats pretty easy to do.

However I am unsure if I still must have the normal MVC controllers also in the design.

[image]

If you have experience in design and architecture, can you please share your thoughts on this?, do you consider this diagram is correct or how should I improve it?

Comment: well, are you using MVC?  Also, ASP.NET 5 combined the controllers into one

Comment: yes I am using MVC but I am not planning to use asp.net 5 for this project,

Comment: You didn't let it clear if you are building a web site (ASP.NET MVC) that happens to also have services (API) or a pure API. If API is the case, you'll only need controllers that inherit from WebApiController.

Comment: its a website that willl consume its own services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow this approach:

- Domain Layer (With your entities, service domain and interfaces)
- Repository Layer (Data access classes)
- Service Layer (Web Api project to expose your data, and be consumed)
- Application Layer (Where you put your ViewModel, and this way you can share between Service Layer(Api) and Web Layer(MVC), and other stuffs like automapper)
- Presentation Layer (Your MVC project)

Like you said, your application is small, but you could follow some principles of [DDD](http://dddcommunity.org/), and always create an application more decoupled, and easy to maintain.

Comment: do you have a diagram of such design?

Comment: Sorry @EstebanV, but you could follow DDD principles, like this image http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-84-75-metablogapi/8750.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_2908B25B.png

Comment: @EstebanV my answer solved your doubt of Architecture desgin?